# WebApi - Autofac cannot resolve parameter HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I have an issue with `RegisterHttpRequestMessage` not working for me and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. This is specifically when I try to manually resolve a service that accepts the HttpMessageRequest as a parameter.

I'm using modules to register components in my builder, and currently my module in the main web project looks like this:

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

builder.RegisterHttpRequestMessage(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
builder.RegisterType<SourceSystemViewModel>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("ViewModelValidator"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .PropertiesAutowired();
// Etc etc etc
```

`SourceSystemViewModel` is currently quite simple and looks like this:

```
public interface ISourceSystemViewModel
{
    SourceSystem Value { get; }
}
public class SourceSystemViewModel : ISourceSystemViewModel
{
    public SourceSystemViewModel(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        Value = request.Headers.GetSourceSystem();
    }
    public SourceSystem Value { get; }
}
```

GetSourceSystem is just an extension method that pulls out the header value. I have tried both registering `SourceSystemViewModel` with and without `InstancePerRequest` but it doesn't make a difference. The moment autofac tries to resolve `ISourceSystemViewModal` (and ultimately `HttpRequestMessage`) it throws this:

> An exception of type
>   'Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException' occurred
>   in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The requested service 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' has not been registered. To avoid
>   this exception, either register a component to provide the service,
>   check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the
>   ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.

Using autofac 3.5 (webapi dll is quoted as autofac.webapi2 3.4).

Any ideas much appreciated!

**Notes**

I'll add any findings as I come across them...

**Update 1**

I took a look at how `RegisterHttpRequestMessage` works and it does indeed add a message handler called `CurrentRequestHandler` to `HttpConfiguration`. When my request comes in I can see that this message handler still exists. So the method *seems* to do what it's supposed to, it's just not resolving the request message for me...

**Update 2**

I have noticed that while in the context of a controller and therefore have access to the `HttpRequestMessage` I can resolve both objects. Like this:

```
ILifetimeScope requestLifetimeScope = Request.GetDependencyScope().GetRequestLifetimeScope();
var h = requestLifetimeScope.Resolve<HttpRequestMessage>();
var sourceSystemViewModel = requestLifetimeScope.Resolve<ISourceSystemViewModel>();
```

**Update 3**

It's important to note that I am manually trying to resolve a service that is expecting the HttpMessageRequest as an injected parameter. For example, this fails for me:

```
using (var httpRequestScope = IocProxy.Container.Context.BeginLifetimeScope("AutofacWebRequest"))
{
    var sourceSystemViewModel = httpRequestScope.Resolve<ISourceSystemViewModel>();
}
```

Comment: Is it might be that you're using a different `HttpConfiguration` (not `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` one) ?

Comment: I don't think so. We're also registering a custom formatter on the Global Config which isn't having any problems. Autofac in general is working fine too.

Comment: Can you try to debug and see all registered registrations? If you say that if message handler exists and has been called, then there should be registration for `HttpRequestMessage`.

Comment: I have already done this and the message handler is still in the Handlers within the HttpConfiguration after a request has been fired. I never said it has been called, but what I have noticed is if I use an existing request while in the controller to generate a ILifetimeScope I can successfully resolve the HttpRequestMessage. I will post an update to the question to show sample code

Comment: So, after your updated, I got the question: where did you try to resolve your `ISourceSystemViewModel` (when you got an error)? I mean on which step/scope. It looks like that you're trying to resolve this somewhere before message handler has been invoked. (in case when you call this inside your controller - handler already is being invoked for sure).

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what happening, but it has led me on to finding out something interesting. If I add ISourceSystem as a parameter to the controller it will resolve fine. But unfortunately, for now, I'm looking to resolve ISourceSystem manually. The reason I need to do it manually is I'm trying to use this in conjunction with FluentValidation and as of yet I don't see a way to inject a parameter into a validator without fluent validation complaining.

Comment: I don't know how you're using FluentValidation and which parameters you need to inject into validator. but you can use [FluentValidation in conjuction with Autofac](https://json.codes/blog/integrating-fluent-validation-with-aspnet-web-api).

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at that. I think my question is badly worded now and is unanswerable in it's current state. I will update it to include the fact I'm trying to manually resolve the HttpMessageRequest.

Comment: I think that it depends on when or inside which scope you perform this. And it might be impossible to do in time when you do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and based on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23725868/1426535) I was able to get it working with

```
    public class NLoggerTraceWriterModule : Module
{

    private HttpConfiguration _config;

    public NLoggerTraceWriterModule(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        this._config = config;
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterInstance(this._config).As<HttpConfiguration>();
        builder.Register(c =>
                           c.Resolve<HttpConfiguration>()
                            .Services
                            .GetService(typeof(ITraceWriter)) as ITraceWriter)
               .As<ITraceWriter>();
    }
}
```

registering this module as

```
// Call RegisterHttpRequestMessage to add the feature.
builder.RegisterHttpRequestMessage(config);
builder.RegisterModule(new Helper.Logging.NLoggerTraceWriterModule(config));
```

Comment: Thanks Rufus. The code has changed slightly due to having to work around this, but I intend to come back to this and verify if your suggestion works as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: Apologies for the massive delay getting back. But I have just checked the solution you've provided and it fixed the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Even though this wasn't the issue for OP, here's another solution since this is currently the only Google result for `"The requested service System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' has not been registered."`

If you've created an `HttpConfiguration` instance, make sure that's what you're passing to the registration function.

In my case, this was resolved by changing this:

```
builder.RegisterHttpRequestMessage(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

To this:

```
builder.RegisterHttpRequestMessage(Startup.HttpConfiguration);
```